# Magento 1.9 - Hide Category product slider out of stock products

Tags: magento-1.9, category-view

I have disabled displaying out of stock items by Admin panel.

But It doesn't hide in category tab slider.

All items are out of stocks as per the below snapshot.How can I get out of this issue??

[image]